# Ionic push - send to external ids

Tags: push-notification, ionic-framework

In the alpha Version of the IonicPush, it was possibe to send pushNotifications to external_ids. In the beta however, i only managed to send pushNotifications to internal ids.

An external_id is connected to a user in my Database, generated with my backend and looks like this: 55f743ed0664427a638c150c295741f8826994707148da4767

So sending a pushNotification to external_ids in the alpha like this was no problem

```
user_ids: array("55f743ed0664427a638c150c295741f8826994707148da4767","55f743ed0664427a638c150c295741f8826994707148da4767","55f743ed0664427a638c150c295741f8826994707148da4767");
```

Now in the beta, the ionicPush Service generates internal_ids for every user, and i can only send pushNotifications to internal_ids. Those internal_ids are not saved in my Database.

```
user_ids: array("5303434a-5f48-4743-9584-15ccb8bf7528","5303434a-5f48-4743-9584-15ccb8bf7528");
```

My problem now is that i have to send pushes via the external id but i am not able to do this anymore. 
A ionic user, which is necessary to send targeted pushes, has an internal id, external id and a name in my case.

**UPDATE: IonicUser**

A ionicUser has a Name, ID and External ID. It is possible to send pushes to the ID but not to the external ID.

[image]

The ionic User saves the Android/iOs Device token

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by Internal and External Id's, but when you use the code:

```
var push = new Ionic.Push({
  "debug": true
});

push.register(function(token) {
  console.log("Device token:",token.token);
});
```

It returns a token. This is the token you can save to the database and then use it to send notifications as described here: http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push.

Comment: So why can't you just switch to using the internal id's?

Comment: oh totally forgot to accept this question. Yeah well i thought i need the ionic users. I rewrote my app so that i send the token to my backend and save it for the currently logged in user. Works like charm